# How to find unused sbt dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt

My build.sbt has a lot of dependencies now. How do I know which dependencies are actually being used?

Maven seems to have dependency:analyse http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/ 
Is there something similar for sbt?

Answer (score 11):

There is [the sbt-explicit-dependencies plugin](https://github.com/cb372/sbt-explicit-dependencies), which has been developed recently. It has direct commands in the SBT console to:

- Enforce explicit direct declaration of dependencies, thus disallowing transitive dependencies.
- Detect and remove unneeded dependencies.

Comment: I couldn't use `unusedCompileDependencies` in a multi-module Scala 2.12 project. It shows wrong results

Answer (score 3):

you can use [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin. it shows dependencies in different graphical representations. also you can try to use [tattletale](http://tattletale.jboss.org/), but it's not integrated with sbt. it'll require you to copy managed dependencies (`retrieveManaged := true`). this tool not only shows dependency graph, but analyzes class usage and can display unused dependencies (including transitive)

Comment: I tried with sbt-dependency-graph, it doesn't give me a list of unused dependencies OOB ?

Comment: use tattletale for this. or you can try [loosejar](https://code.google.com/p/loosejar/) but i have not tried it.